# Reference for proof of Kaloujnine-Krasner

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

The theorem of Kaloujnine-Krasner says

> Given two groups $D$ and $Q$, the wreath product $D \wr Q$ contains an isomorphic copy of every extension of $D$ by $Q$.

I am looking for an English reference of a complete proof.

In Rotman's Group Theory book, the theorem can be found for $Q$ finite (Theorem 7.37, fourth ed.) but this is not enough for my purposes. Supposedly, a full proof can be found in Kargapolov & Merzliakov's "Eléments de la théorie des groupes" but it's in French.

> Can anyone point me to a proof written in English?

Comment: I don't think that the proof in Rotman really assumes that $Q$ is finite and I am not certain why he assumed that. It may be because he didn't want to discuss the difference between the wreath product and the restricted wreath product. For this theorem you need the full wreath product in which the base group is the unrestricted direct product of copies of $D$. In the restricted version, only finitely many components of the base group are allowed to be nontrivial. It is confusing, because I have seen statement about wreath products that refer to the restricted wreath product.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks for your comment, Derek. You seem to be right that Rotman's proof also works for the infinite case if one uses the full wreath product. Rotman defines the wreath product only for finite cartesian products but then later states that one can also work with infinitely many copies (he calls the full wreath product the complete wreath product). It unclear to me why he only gives a restricted definition since it doesn't seem to make things any easier...

Comment: Look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_embedding_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try C. Wells, "Some applications of the wreath product construction", Amer. Math. Monthly 83 (1976), no. 5, 317–338.

While I cannot say whether your particular application occurs in that paper, I've found it to be a good source on wreath product stuff more generally, including some work of Kaloujnin-Krasner, so yours might be in there.